# How to modify an actionscript function and execute it in a webpage?

Tags: actionscript, execute

I have an actionscript function that, after modifying some values and "executing" it, it has to return some specific result, my question is:

Is there a way to build a webpage that let users modify that function using a form and then execute it in order to get a result?

How do I "execute" actionscript functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you say modifying a function, do you want the user to create a function on the fly, and allow him to execute it?
Or you simply want to pass some arguments to an already existing function and then do some calculation and return the result?

Incase you simply want to execute a function within actionscript, from javascript, you can use ExternalInterface in ActionScript 3.0 , define a function and allow javascript to call that function.

```
public function functionToBeCalledFromJS(argument1,argument2)
{
Alert.show(argument1);
}

ExternalInterface.addCallBack('ASfunction',functionToBeCalledFromJS);

In JS when user submits a form call: 

ASfunction(argument1,argument2);
```

Incase you want to return some data from AS to JS, then you need to call a JS function from within AS.
This can be easily accomplished using ExternalInterface.call();

Eg.
Lets say, you needed to do some calculation and then return the data

```
public function functionToBeCalledFromJS(argument1,argument2)
{
var returnInt:int = argument1+argument2;
}
ExternalInterface.call('JSFunction',returnInt);

IN JS:
function JSFunction(result)
{
alert(result);

}
```

For further details on this, you can go to http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29, which is the official site on AS3 reference.

Comment: Thanks, thanks... The thing is, I "want to pass some arguments to an already existing function and then do some calculation and return the result" just as you said... In fact, the user only needs to input an URL in order to this function to parse all the data that it needs to return the result, But, I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO THAT! I'm totally Lost... I read in one page that is possible to build a "Flex App" that contains two files: one mxml that is able to call the ActionScript and second the ActionScript file, then you build it and like magic, you get it... But Don't understand quite well...